# Typescript include and file path VS Code recognition

Tags: javascript, typescript, autocomplete, visual-studio-code, tsconfig

I have been struggling for a while now with the inclusion of my tsconfig files into VS Code.
Whereas my code compiles just fine, I often have errors reported by VS Code, because VS Code did not associate the tsconfig file to the current ts file.

I check if my main.ts file is associated to any tsconfig in VS Code by executing the following:

> TypeScript: Go to Project Configuration

I received an error (see link below) telling my that no tsconfig is found. 
You can also see the folder strucutre in the linked image.

To give a short overview the structure looks like this:

```
root
`-- development
    `--client
       |
       |--code
       |    |--.. various
       |    `-- main.ts
       |
       `--config
            |--.. various
            `--tsconfig.json
```

My tsconfig.json looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2015",
    "target": "es2017",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "./../code/**/*"
  ],
  "files": [
    "./../code/main.ts"
  ]
}
```

[VS Code Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXpHW.png)

Comment: From the TS docs (http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) it looks like `tsconfig.json` has to be in the project root, which is why VSCode only looks for it there.

Comment: I have multiple tsconfigs and therefore cannot simply put them in the root folder. Also some of them are recognized even when not in the root folder (well, as mentioned above, all of them are recognized by the compiler but not all by VS Code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that VSCode looks up from the ts file to find a tsconfig (https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3772#issuecomment-329126952)

If you move the client tsconfig up a directory it should work.

```
root
`-- development
    `--client
       |--tsconfig.json
       |
       |--code
       |    |--.. various
       |    `-- main.ts
       |
       `--config
            `--.. various
```

As the comment suggests you might want to add a `tsconfig.base.json` to the `root` folder and include it in each `tsconfig.json` so that you can have some common/default settings.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `tsconfig.json` to the root of your project, and change the paths accordingly:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2015",
    "target": "es2017",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "development/client/code/**/*"
  ],
  "files": [
    "development/client/code/main.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I have multiple tsconfigs and therefore cannot simply put them in the root folder. Also some of them are recognized even when not in the root folder (well, as mentioned above, all of them are recognized by the compiler but not all by VS Code)